# Incoming call notification

Tags: android, notifications, call

How can I programmatically notify an incoming call?

I am developing an application in which if the user is suppose to reject a call then a message should be sent automatically to the caller with a predefined text.

Comment: I would never install an app that does this.  My phone is, first and foremost, a phone.  I don't _want_ any app to supersede the phone.  And even if it did, I wouldn't want it spending my money sending automated text messages.  Is this really what you want your app to do?

Comment: @Sparky: But maybe others do. He is quite sure that he wants to do this if he is asking for help on how to do it.